# C++ MFC ocx in a C# project, pointer parameters

Tags: c#, pointers, parameters, activex, ocx

I have ported succesful a old MFC project made in VC6 to VS2010. This project makes an ocx file that I can use as activeX in a C# and paste into my winform (drag/drop).

No problem until there. When I try to find my routines everthing comes up. Some of the functions rendering images into this OCX control. For this routine I need to pass parameters. 
Its a long type parameter in C++. This parameter is a pointer (that is used a lot in C++).

In c# in other hands we got some restrictions. Some data types cant be used. When I look to the type in C# I see its INT32. Due the conversion to int32 it removes my pointer from 0FF55885 is to 0.

What is the best approach to work with pointers in C# and how do I get rit of the conversion?

Edit: some more info

This is my c++ function:
AddPixelMatrix(long lID,..., long l2DPixelArray, long lWidth, long lHeight, long lColorArray,long lNofColors, long lStretchWithImage)

in my c#

axImgView1.AddPixelMatrix(parameter1,...); all parameters are type int

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer can be marshalled as `System.IntPtr`.